# Will producers be blocked if one of the brokers goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have these settings:

```
min.insync.replicas = 2
replicator-factor = 3
acks=all
```

Will producers be blocked if one broker goes down? Or can we still continue to produce?

I am trying to understand the meaning of min.insync.replicas - does this mean Kafka will only keep two replicas in-sync?  Or does it mean it only needs two replicas to acknowledge writes?

Comment: Once ack from 2 replicas is received, the write is considered successful.

Answer (score 0):

No, if one broker goes down and you have the settings as mentioned the producer will not throw an error.

And yes, it means only two acknowledgments (based on configuration `acks`) are needed for a successful write.

In the Kafka documentation in section [topic level configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) you will find a description exactly describing your case:

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception (either NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend).
> When used together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater durability guarantees. **A typical scenario would be to create a topic with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write.**